# Oracle Apex UTIL_URL Cache issue

Tags: oracle-apex

I apologise as I cannot explain this by pasting the exact code or demo due to restrictions but will try my best to explain the issue.

I have an interactive grid for employee details. (Page 1)
One column is link to another pop-up page(Page 2) where previously the values were coming using page as target and items were referenced to be stored in session. `P2_EMPNO` -> `&EMPNO.`
Second column, stores the value filled in pop-up page for P2_EMPNO as the Updated EMPNO.

We changed it and instead we use `Apex_util.get_url` where p_item was -> `P2_EMPNO`
and p_value was `EMPNO`.

What happened was, when we clicked on link, P2_EMPNO was showing the value passed from page 1. But whatever Empno was entered. Update it was copying the same empno for all records unless value was overriden.
Ex: For a different row if I just click update it would still update the same empno instead of leaving it empty.

In `APEX_UTIL.GET_URL` I added p_clear_cache => '2' to clear cache for page 2. But now when i click on link i do not see the rows P2_EMPNO value what was updated.
i.e. once i update P2_EMPNO and value is updated in the second column, then when i click again in the pop-up i should see the same EMPNO , but it doesn't show.

How can this be handled?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible case for me to have a look ? Use apex.oracle.com, workspace SO_HELP. Log in with  user/pwd SO_76181687/SO_76181687. It has emp/dept sample data alraedy. Create a new app for your issue